# Distinct count on a rolling time window

Tags: sql, count, db2, sliding-window

I want to count the number of **distinct** catalog numbers that have appeared within the last X minutes. This is usually called a rolling time window.

For instance, if I have:

```
row        startime            orderNumber    catalogNumb
1        2007-09-24-15.50       o1              21    
2        2007-09-24-15.51       o2              21
3        2007-09-24-15.52       o2              21
4        2007-09-24-15.53       o3              21
5        2007-09-24-15.54       o4              22
6        2007-09-24-15.55       o4              23
7        2007-09-24-15.56       o4              21
8        2007-09-24-15.57       o4              21
```

For instance, if I want to get this for the last 5 minutes (5 is just one of the possible values), the output should be:

```
row        startime            orderNumber    catalogNumb    countCatalog
1        2007-09-24-15.50       o1              21                 1
2        2007-09-24-15.51       o2              22                 2
3        2007-09-24-15.52       o2              23                 3
4        2007-09-24-15.53       o3              24                 4
5        2007-09-24-15.54       o4              21                 4
6        2007-09-24-15.55       o4              21                 4 
7        2007-09-24-15.56       o4              21                 4
8        2007-09-24-15.57       o4              21                 3
```

I am using Big SQL for infosphere BigInsights v3.0.
Resulting query can use any db2 [Olap](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_olapspecification.html) windows functions except for 
count (distinct catalogNumb) OVER()... which is not supported by my db2 version.

In addition to count, I may also need to use other aggregate functions (avg, sum...) over the catalogNumb and other attributes.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide information on your Db2 version and platform

Comment: @data_henrik I am using Db2 11 and RapidMiner 8 as IDE

Comment: @data_henrik sorry I am actually using Big SQL for infosphere BigInsights v3.0

Answer (score 0):

True Db2 does not support count distinct as OLAP function but there is an easy workaround:

You can use

> dense_rank

instead - the highest number (max) from dense rank is your count distinct!

Comment: Any idea of how I can use the dense_rank on the time sliding window. That is, calculate the rank over the last X minutes?

Comment: You have to provide more details about the logic you need

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select ...
  from mytable
  where starttime between current_time - 5 minutes and current_time
```

That will get all the rows for the last 5 minutes. `5` can be a variable. then count() or sum() or average() the rows.