# Create moving count of rows where datetime column is between row value and one day earlier

Tags: pandas

I have a very large dataframe with a datetime column. I want to know how many rows there are between each rows datetime value and a day day earlier. I have tried using `df.rolling` but it doesn't seem to allow for a dynamic window size.

e.g. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
datetime_col
01-01-2022 01:00:00
01-01-2022 02:00:00
01-01-2022 03:00:00
01-01-2022 03:30:00
01-02-2022 02:30:00
01-03-2022 01:00:00
01-04-2022 01:00:00
01-04-2022 12:00:00
01-05-2022 11:00:00
```

And I would like the expected output to be this:

```
datetime_col          moving_count 
01-01-2022 01:00:00   1
01-01-2022 02:00:00   2  
01-01-2022 03:00:00   3
01-01-2022 03:30:00   4
01-02-2022 02:30:00   3
01-03-2022 01:00:00   2
01-04-2022 01:00:00   2
01-04-2022 12:00:00   2
01-05-2022 11:00:00   2
```

Notice how the `moving_count` number calculates the number of rows that are a day less than the date in that row

Comment: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Please, Include what you tried, and give sample data with expected results, so no one can mis-interpret your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count on a rolling time window in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968486/count-on-a-rolling-time-window-in-pandas)

Comment: The date `01-02-2022 02:30:00` in your expected results is not present in you input data

Comment: A solution in MySQL: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OQwCDHWi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), indexes are needed(correct me if this is not true). Made an index from the 'datetime_col' column and created a 'moving_count' with zeros (if you have a column other than 'datetime_col' , then you don't have to create it).

```
import pandas as pd

df['datetime_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_col'])

df['moving_count'] = 0
df = df.set_index('datetime_col')


print(df['moving_count'].rolling('1D', min_periods=1).count())
```

Output
datetime_col

```
2022-01-01 01:00:00    1.0
2022-01-01 02:00:00    2.0
2022-01-01 03:00:00    3.0
2022-01-01 03:30:00    4.0
2022-01-02 02:30:00    3.0
2022-01-03 01:00:00    2.0
2022-01-04 01:00:00    1.0
2022-01-04 12:00:00    2.0
2022-01-05 11:00:00    2.0
```

And note that in line 7, count=1. To count inclusive, you can take 1440 minutes (this is a day) + 1 minute. Here are the string notation for times and dates: [see](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

```
print(df['moving_count'].rolling('1441T', min_periods=1).count())
```